# Second mutable borrow occurs here error in rust

Tags: rust

I want to make a function that compose given function twice, i.e., f(f(x)) in Rust. Here is my code:

```
pub fn compose<T, F: FnMut(T) -> T>(mut f: F) -> impl FnMut(T) -> T {
    move |x| f(f(x))
}
```

But I got this error message:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `f` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/lib.rs:2:16
  |
2 |     move |x| f(f(x))
  |              - ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
  |              |
  |              first mutable borrow occurs here
  |              first borrow later used by call

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the intermediate step into a variable that no longer requires the borrow of f. Something like

```
pub fn compose<T, F: FnMut(T) -> T>(mut f: F) -> impl FnMut(T) -> T {
    move |x| {
        let tmp = f(x);
        f(tmp)
    }
}
```